# AngularJS: Unable to read radio button value in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a calendar like grid which generates numbers from 1 to 31 using two ng-repeats. Each element of the grid is a radio button, whose value I want to get inside a controller.

For example, user clicks on '12', the value gets stored somewhere, and on click of submit propagates to the controller.

The problem is that I am unable to read the value of the element checked.

Code:

```
   <div data-toggle="buttons">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="date in dates track by $index" ng-if="$index % 5 == 0">
                  <label ng-class="{'btn-online': isOnline(i+1), 'btn-paper': isPaper(i+1)}" class="singleDate btn btn-default col-no-gutter col-xs-2 letter-box" 
                       ng-repeat="i in [$index, $index + 1, $index + 2, $index + 3, $index + 4]" 
                       ng-if="dates[i] != null">
                            <input type="radio" name="dates" id="date-{{i+1}}" ng-model="$parent.dueDate" ng-value="{{date[i]}}" class="date radio radio-primary">{{dates[i]}} 
                  </label>
            </div> <!--row div ends here -->
            {{dueDate}} <!--no output here as well-->
        </div> 


        <button type="submit" ng-click="changeDueDate(dueDate)" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Change Payment Due Date</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Don't Bind to Primitives

```
<!-- instead bind to objects -->

<button type="submit" ng-click="changeDueDate(obj.dueDate)">
  Change Payment Due Date
</button>
```

Each `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` adds a new scope and level of hierarchy. Instead of counting levels of hierarchy, make `dueDate` a property of an object, `obj.dueDate`. Then prototypical inheritance will do its magic properly. For more information, see [The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).